# can someone fix this SQL code for me?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, execution

In this code i got #1064 error at line 5. can somebody rewrite the code; Thank you

```html
  CREATE FUNCTION thuva.CreateGroup(GroupName VARCHAR(50), GroupIcon TEXT, GroupDescription VARCHAR(130), GroupCreator INT)
  RETURNS int(11)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE groupID INT;
  INSERT INTO groups (name, icon, description) VALUES (GroupName, GroupIcon, GroupDescription);
  SET groupID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO group_members VALUES (groupID, GroupCreator);
  RETURN groupID;
END;
```

Comment: Do you have a `DELIMITER` statement?

Comment: works fine with delimiter wrappers http://pastebin.com/zWQQifwN

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax

```
DECLARE variable_name datatype [ DEFAULT initial_value ]
```

since its a datatype you need to define size something like.

```
DECLARE groupID INT(11);
```